# right shift bool in C++

Tags: c++, integer-arithmetic

In given code, a bool has been passed on to `foo` as shown in `mainFunc`. I am not sure if `e >> 24` is a right thing to do in `foo`. I believe this will only give garbage values.

```
void foo(bool e){
   int a;
   bool s;
   e = e >> 24;
   ...
}

void mainFunc(){
   int *arg = (int*)malloc(sizeof(int));
   *arg = xxxx;   

   foo(*(bool*)arg);
}
```

Is this a right thing to do?

EDIT: I was more concerned about operation `e >> 24`, since e is bool. won't this lead to any issue? Apologies for any misunderstanding.

Comment: I can't really make sense of the question. The same thing happens to the other 3 bytes as happens to the fourth byte -- nothing at all. When you convert "three" to "3", nothing happens to the "three" -- it stays precisely the same. You just also have a "3' to do things with.

Comment: if `sizeof(bool)` is 1, there are no "other 3 bytes"

Comment: 0 is false, all other values are true. It's not like only the low 8 bits of the int are used in the conversion...

Comment: I am not sure if `e >> 24` is a valid command to use. since e is bool.

Comment: So, just to confirm, the question implied by the title, the question implied by the first paragraph, and the question implied by your `mainFunc` - _none_ of these are what you actually wanted to ask? Just remove them and ask a single question!

Comment: I'll edit the question for you if you want, so long as you confirm my understanding is right.

Comment: @Useless I have updated the question now?

Comment: And yet the title and more than half of the code are still irrelevant, as far as I can see. Is it really just the right-shift you're interested in?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I was more concerned about operation `e >> 24`, since `e` is `bool`. won't this lead to any issue?

Built-in arithmetic operators do not operate on types smaller than `int`, see [integral promotion](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/implicit_conversion#Integral_promotion) for more details. In expression `e = e >> 24;` `e` is `bool` and to shift it right the compiler first promotes the value of `e` to `int`, does the shift and then converts the result back to `bool`. The result is always `int` `0`, which gets converted to `bool` `false`. Unless the `sizeof(int) <= 3`, in which case shifting it 24 bits or more is undefined behaviour.

Answer (score 0):

The cast to `bool` just creates a new boolean value to pass to `foo`. Nothing at all happens to any of the four bytes that `arg` points to. They remain precisely the same.